# I used st_set_crs to include my crs but it is giving me the geometry in meters not degrees

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, r-sf, units-of-measurement

I got a shape file from http://www.savgis.org/Ecuador/provincias.zip without the CRS and I want to add it. I found that for my data the values are EPSG:24878, PSAD56 / UTM zone 18S https://epsg.io/24878. I did this

```
Ecuador<- read_sf("provincias.shp")
st_crs(Ecuador) # no CRS
Ecuador=st_set_crs(Ecuador,24878) # add crs to the data
st_crs(Ecuador) # works
st_area(Ecuador) # area is not right
```

I checked the geometry is `<MULTIPOLYGON [m]>` , I want to know how to change it or how should I add the right CRS units.
The final area should be around `250747.1 [km^2]`

Thanks

Comment: They are the right CRS units for that projection. The units are metres. There are instructions to convert units here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/291